# Scale image relative to itself via CSS, but keep flow of surrounding elements?

Tags: css, firefox

I have a JavaScript HTML-string generation function which (via a regex before display) turns user-provided text with certain image URLs like

```
Hello http://example.com/1.png world World
```

into

```
Hello <img src="http://example.com/1.png" style="zoom: 2" alt=""> World
```

The images are of varying and unknown dimensions, and the "zoom: 2" is meant to double their size, while keeping the surrounding flow of the text parts. This works fine in Chrome, but fails to resize in Firefox, and when using the Firefox-compatible approach of

```
transform: scale(2); transform-origin: left top;
```

then the text flow isn't preserved, but overlaps with the image (e.g. the "Hello" is now covered). How could I fix this for Firefox? Thanks!

Comment: How about you get the images width, multiply it by two and then assign it to the image. You are working with Javascript already...

Comment: Yes that's true, though the images aren't yet loaded at that point. I might go that route though for Firefox if no pure CSS option is available. I guess that would be something in the vicinity of `<img src="..." onload="this.width *= 2; this.height *= 2">`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the size of the image using `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` and double the values retrieved

```html
Hello <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/100/100?a=1" 
           alt="" onload="
                  this.width = this.naturalWidth * 2; 
                  this.height = this.naturalHeight * 2;
       "> World
```